# Cannot do rmdir sftp permission issue?

Tags: linux, permissions, sftp

```
sftp> ls -ltr
drwxrwxrwx   1 user     group           0 Aug 28  2018 Processed_20180828_131645
drwxrwxrwx   1 user     group           0 Aug 29  2018 Processed_20180828_190042
sftp> rmdir Processed_20180828_131645
Couldn't remove directory: Permission denied
```

This is parent folder permission:

```
drwxrwxrwx   1 user     group           0 Aug 31  2018 2018
```

I am not sure why its not deleting the folder? is there any other permission required?

My username is test123

Answer (score 0):

Add you user to file group, then reload sftp and remove this file.
Check if you can make a file on this directory, if not your user does not have permission for this local directory.
If you do not have permission, reload/restart this service and try again.